# Java LinkedHashSet not removing duplicates even after overriding equals and hashCode methods

Tags: java, set, linkedhashset

I am trying to remove duplicates from a List of objects by adding all the objects in the list to a Set and adding the data back to the list. My code is as follows:

```
List<LocationHourListHB> locationHoursList = new ArrayList<LocationHourListHB>();
Set<LocationHourListHB> locationHoursSet = new LinkedHashSet<LocationHourListHB>();
locationHoursSet.addAll(locationHoursList);
locationHoursList.clear();
locationHoursList.addAll(locationHoursSet);
```

I have `LocationHourListHB` as follows:

```
public class LocationHourListHB {
    private String startTIme;
    private String endTime;

    public String getStartTIme() {
        return startTIme;
    }
    public void setStartTIme(String startTIme) {
        this.startTIme = startTIme;
    }
    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }
    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof LocationHourDay)) {
            return false;
        }

        LocationHourListHB locationHour = (LocationHourListHB) o;

        return locationHour.startTIme.equalsIgnoreCase(startTIme) &&
                locationHour.endTime.equalsIgnoreCase(endTime);
    }

    //Idea from effective Java : Item 9
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + startTIme.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + endTime.hashCode();
        return result;
    }


}
```

I have added the override methods to equals() and hashCode(), but my list still contains duplicates. Is there anything that I am missing here.

Comment: Note: could use `Objetcs.hash()` to calculate the hash code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `equals` method shouldn't check:

```
if (!(o instanceof LocationHourDay)) {
    return false;
}
```

It should check:

```
if (!(o instanceof LocationHourListHB)) {
    return false;
}
```

Since it is comparing `LocationHourListHB` instances.

Comment: let me check, not sure how I missed that

Comment: this is not an answer, it is a question!  [:-P  ((*just kidding, in case someone didn't understand the smiley*))

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I re-phrased that ;)

Comment: Can u provide some object instances as well to make sure that its not happening for your objects only. By object instances I mean what values do you have in starttme and endtime.